# Iframe not working on heroku

Tags: heroku

I have this code

```
  <iframe src="http://matrix.crebtools.com/Matrix/public/IDX.aspx?idx=5a251ec" width="860px" height="520px"></iframe>
```

It work locally but its not working on heroku 
On heroku it shows white empty space

so i put in application.rb this code but its still not working

In applications.rb

```
module MohamedHatata
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
  'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL'
}
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

I spend two days just to try figure out the solution please any one help me

This is my website
https://mohamed-hatata.herokuapp.com/downsizes/new

Comment: Try to open `http://mohamed-hatata.herokuapp.com/downsizes/new` in incognito and you will see iframe content getting loaded just fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you open your javascript console you will find `mixed content` warning.

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://mohamed-hatata.herokuapp.com/downsizes/new' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
>   'http://matrix.crebtools.com/Matrix/public/IDX.aspx?idx=5a251ec'. This
>   request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

If you visit your site at `http://mohamed-hatata.herokuapp.com/downsizes/new` instead of `https://mohamed-hatata.herokuapp.com/downsizes/new` your iframe loads fine.

`config.action_dispatch.default_headers` is to be set by the site which is getting loaded inside your application and not by your application itself.

Read more on Mixed Content - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Security/MixedContent

Comment: Really :D thnxx ,Where Should i set this code config.action_dispatch.default_headers ?

Comment: You need not set this in your application. This header should be set by `matrix.crebtools.com` so that you are allowed to embed there site.

Comment: Hey @nour, did you find any solution for this? I am having the same issue. Thanks